# copy/paste style to multiple layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

I have many shapefiles in QGIS. How can I paste the style of one layer to **all** the other ones? So a "batch" copy and paste solution.

If I make a multiple selection the the paste style option is not available anymore.